# Count the number of times a string appears in a specific column

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

I have several columns with 3 possible results that are:

> 1. Yes
> 2. No
> 3. N.A.(Not Apply)

How can I create a card visualization with the total number of times that the word 'No' appears in the selected columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this you can count the number of times a particular entity has been repeated in that column

```
len(df[df['column_name'] == "Yes"])
```

Just replace the value to other types if needed for various values of column like Yes,No,N.A

Answer (score 0):

You can use value_counts() for the counting

```
   df['column_name'].value_counts()
```